# add x number of every 10th element

Tags: javascript, for-loop, count

I want to add number of every 10th element.

For example,

```
function myFunction() {

    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    { 

        var d = i;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += d+"<br/>";

    }

}
```

Output:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100

But, I want like this

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40....

I want to add 5 after 10th number, add 10 after 20th number, add 15 after 30th number, add 20 after 40th number, add 25 after 50th number. I know this is simple. But, I couldn't get any result.

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2pjekt1/3/)**

Comment: `add 10 after 20th number`  So why isn't your example showing.. `..24,25,36,37...`?  Also it looks like your adding 6 after 10, and 6 after 20, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the modulo operator `%` to check if the current number (`i`) is a multiple of 10, then if it is, add 5 to `i`:

```
if (i % 10 === 0) {
  i += 5;
}
```

Moreover, I recommend that you keep a string of all the numbers you want to append to your page, as querying and adding contents to the DOM each loop iteration is an expensive operation which can be avoided

See example below:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var resultStr = ""
  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    resultStr += i + "<br/>";
    if (i % 10 === 0) {
      i += 5;
    }
  }
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += resultStr;
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could take an offset and increment this value by five if the result of the index variable is dividable by ten.

```js
var i,
    offset = 0,
    result = [];
    
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    result.push(i + offset);
    if (i % 10 === 0) offset += 5;
}
console.log(result.join(' '));
```

Comment: The OP say's -> `I want to add 5 after 10th number, add 10 after 20th number, add 15 after 30th number`,  but his example output is not doing that either,.. So might need more clarification from OP here.

Comment: @Keith, text vs example. i took the example, because some text may lead to a wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

I used a counter to account for in increment on the 10th element, and am simply putting the results on the console. Obviously there are some that would simply just add 5, the counter option is just a design preference.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21];
function myFunction(arr){
  var counter = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if (i%10 ==0){
      counter++;
    }
    arr[i] = arr[i]+(5*(counter-1));
  }
  console.log(arr);
};

myFunction(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your fucntion like that:

```
function myFunction() {

  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        var d = i;
    if (i > 1 && i % 10 === 1) {
            d = (i % 10) * 5 + i;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += d + ",";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
function myFunction() {

    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    { 
        var j=Math.floor(i/10);
        var x=5*j;
        var d = x+i;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += d+"<br/>";

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the performance issue presented by Nick Parsons

```
var resultStr = ""
  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    resultStr += i + "<br/>";
    if (i % 10 === 0) {
      i += 5;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += resultStr;
```

innerHTML is just horribly slow. 
Consider the following code that employs a document fragment and the vanilla .append() method

```
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        if( i % 10 === 0 )
            i += 5;
        fragment.append( document.createTextNode( i ) );
        fragment.append( document.createElement('BR') );
    }
document.getElementById('demo').append( fragment );
```

[From my testing](https://jsperf.com/for-loops-append-vs-innerhtml/1), it's  about 2000(!) times faster to use a document fragment.